# Appache 2.4 - Reverse Proxy with location directive not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm facing problem in apache2.4 reverse proxy.

**Appache config**:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://domain2.com"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://domain2.com/"
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
# If the path restricted cookie is set or the request asks for Javascript, images, or other content we don't need to protect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} t_path=.+
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?!(html|htm|pdf))
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [P,QSA]

# If we have a token in the query string, verify it
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(/.*)      /auth/?path=$1 [passthrough,QSA]

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]


<Location /test>
        SetHandler modperl
        PerlOptions +GlobalRequest
        PerlResponseHandler test::Handler
</Location>
```

If i hit url http://domain1.com/abc/cdb/?t=787986 in browser, its throws error as "`The requested URL /auth/ was not found on this server.`" Also if i do the steps as "remove reverse proxy lines->restart apache->hit url in browser->add reverse proxy lines-restart apache", works fine(may be cahed). `test::Handler` will check the valid url and their params and set return redirection url. there was proble in reverse proxy and location. Please someone help me to get resolved.

Comment: Need the below behavior: 1. Browser url: http://domain1.com/abc/cdb/?t=787986
2. Request http://domain1.com/auth from set handler. validate url in sethandler called file
3. After validate, handler function redirect to url: http://domain1.com/abc/cdb/?t=787986
4. Finally call reverse url and show their contents.

Comment: above codes works fine in apache2 but not in apache2.4